# how to use custom tags with namespace in rss?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to create custom tags with namespace for rss feed. I have listed both of my files rss.xml & rss.xsl below for reference. If I remove rss element from xml document, it is working fine. with rss element it is not working.

anybody have any idea?

here is my XML document - rss.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="rss.xsl"?>
<rss version='2.0' xmlns:SL="http://mywebsite.com/course.xsd">
<channel><description>mywebsite Course RSS Feed</description><link>http://www.mywebsite.com</link><title>mywebsite Courses</title>
<SL:Courses>
<SL:Course>
<SL:ID>18</SL:ID>
<SL:Name>ITIL<sup>Â®</sup> Foundation</SL:Name>
<SL:WorkshopId>17369</SL:WorkshopId>
<SL:PackageId>46</SL:PackageId>
<SL:Dates>11-Jan-2014,12-Jan-2014</SL:Dates>
<SL:StartDate>11-Jan-2014</SL:StartDate>
<SL:EndDate>12-Jan-2014</SL:EndDate>
<SL:StartTiming>09:30</SL:StartTiming>
<SL:EndTiming>18:30</SL:EndTiming>
<SL:CityId>55</SL:CityId>
<SL:CityName>PUNE</SL:CityName>
<SL:CountryId>6</SL:CountryId>
<SL:CountryName>INDIA</SL:CountryName>
</SL:Course>
</SL:Courses>
</channel>
</rss>
```

here is my xsl document - rss.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" doctype-system='http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd' doctype-public='-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN' />

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<xsl:apply-templates select="//*[local-name()='Courses']" />
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='Courses']">
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="75%">
<xsl:apply-templates select="//*[local-name()='Course']" />
</table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='Course']">
<!-- ... -->
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;padding-top:10px;">
<xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='Name']" disable-output-escaping="yes" /><br />
</td>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;padding-top:10px;">
<xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='Dates']" disable-output-escaping="yes" /><br />
</td>
</tr>
<!-- ... -->
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited my xsl file as you suggested. but no luck. I am sending the updated xsl file here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/m4gwQEjy

Comment: please check and let me know if i am doing something wrong here, thanks

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** (thanks to @nwellnhof): The `rss` element is not prefixed with `SL:`. Thus, even if it assigns a namespace to its child elements, it stays in the default namespace.

In other words, if you want a template to match `rss`, you can do so without adding a namespace prefix. On the other hand, to match the descendants of `rss`, you need to declare their namespace (or use `local-name()`).

So, a namespace present in your input XML must also be declared in your XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:SL="http://mywebsite.com/course.xsd">
```

Note that namespaces are not a plague to be avoided using `local-name()`, but a reliable way of identifying elements. If you add the namespace with the prefix `SL` as shown above, simply prefix the template matches with `SL` - instead of matching their local name:

```
<xsl:template match="SL:Courses">
```

---

Now, how to rewrite your stylesheet? Start with matching the document node as you have done already:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

Then, insert a template matching `rss` (n.b. without a namespace prefix), for example:

```
<xsl:template match="rss">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

The templates that follow must include the `SL` prefix, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="SL:Name">
```

Comment: The `rss` element is still in the default namespace, so `SL:rss` will *not* work.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I should get coffee. But before that, I'll edit my post.